# DB2 - find same rec between 2 big files

Tags: sql, db2, subquery, where-clause

I have 2 files with same structure (20 fields)
and I must find if there exist equal record.
The problem is that this files have more that 40 millions recs.

So I have start a SELECT like:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
  WHERE FIELD1||FIELD2||FIELD3||FIELD4...etc
  IN (SELECT FIELD1||FIELD2||FIELD3||FIELD4...etc
        FROM TABLE_B)
```

I have started more that 24 hours ago.

Can anybody tell me please if there is a more quick solution and how can I improved it please ?

Thanks all in advance

Denis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend `exists`:

```
select *
from table_a a
where exists (
    select 1
    from table_b b
    where b.field1 = a.field1 and b.field2 = a.field2 and ...
);
```

The benefits are:

- correctness: this checks for exact matches, while the method that concatenates the string may generate fake positives (not to mention conversion problems if some columns are not strings)
- performance: the expression in the `from` clause of the subquery is SARGable; if you were to create an index on at least a subset of these 40 columns, the database probably could take advantage of it when executing the query

Note: this does not properly handle `null` values; if you want to consider `null` values as equal, then you need more complicated expressions:

```
where 
    (b.field1 = a.field1 or (b.field1 is null and a.field1 is null))
    and (b.field2 = a.field2 or (b.field2 is null and a.field2 is null))
    and ...
```

Comment: Great!!! I like it. I will try it tomorow :-)  Thanks a lot.

Comment: FYI you can use `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` to avoid needing to explicitly check NULLs. See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r_predicate_distinct.html

Comment: Thanks all :-) I can't give "useful" cause I have not yet necessary reputation.

Answer (score 0):

The quick to write method is

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM TABLE_B
```

but performance wise there can be better ways, even if they can be more complex to code.

Still, it will better and more correct than concatenating columns (which will fail if you have NULLs or (possibly) variable length strings)